# Is it possible for a react-script app to export the routes for easy consumption by NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, nginx-location, server-side-rendering

## Context

I am deploying a ReactJS based app to NGINX to be client side rendered. NGINX is serving static files as follows:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```

This works great on the main route `/` which serves index.html and then the client side router kicks in and renders the page.

### Versions

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.6"
  },
```

## Problems

If we have a route like `/abc` in React. This needs to be client side rendered. The trouble is if someone bookmarks the route, or shares it, or publishes it to a search engine etc... then if a browser requests `/abc` in NGINX then it doesn't find a `/abc` location block or file so results in a `404`.

## My Current Proposed Solution

I could add a route to NGINX for each known route as follows:

```
location /abc {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
      }
```

Alternatively, I could modify the default location block try_files directive as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
  }
```

The first approach seems nicer because I explicitly define the acceptable route. So a request for `/xyz`- which isn't a valid route, would result in a 404 - which is what I want.  However, it requires that I define each route which might become a maintenance issue unless I can efficiently automate it.

I propose that part of the CI build does something like:

```
cat src/components/Routes/Routes.js \
| grep -i route | grep "path" \
| tr '"' "'" \
| grep  -o -E "path=['\"]{1}(.*)['\"]{1}" \
| cut -d "=" -f 2 \
| tr -d "'"
```

And then uses this output to generate the NGINX location blocks based on the route.

```
while read -r route; do
    echo "    try_files \$uri /index.html;" >> ${ROUTES}
    echo "}" >> ${ROUTES}
done <<< "${ROUTES}"
```

E.g. an input like:

```
class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return [
      <Header {...this.props} key='header' />,
      <Switch key='content'>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeMVP} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route exact path='/privacy' component={Privacy} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    ];
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
/
/about
/privacy
```

I could then generate the NGINX routes that return `index.html` to allow the client side router to then kick in and render the correct page.

## Question

Does anyone know of a better approach either using NGINX or some feature of react JS/reach scripts to export the routes in a more simple way than using my proposed script above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the following script inside the dockerfile at build time (`nginx:1.14-alpine`):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

ROUTES_FILE=/etc/nginx/dynamic-routes.conf

# Extract all of the routes (except "/")
ROUTES=$(grep -i route /etc/nginx/routes.js \
| grep "path" \
| tr '"' "'" \
| grep  -o -E "path='(.*)'" \
| grep  -v "'/'" \
| cut -d "=" -f 2 \
| tr -d "'")

# Now the routes contain the URI's, e.g. "/about" and "/privacy" loop through and generate NGINX routes.
echo "Routes are: ${ROUTES}"

for route in ${ROUTES}
do
    echo "Generating location for route: ${route}"
    echo "location ~ ${route}[/]?$ {" >> ${ROUTES_FILE}
    echo "    try_files \$uri /index.html;" >> ${ROUTES_FILE}
    echo "}" >> ${ROUTES_FILE}
done

echo "Dynamic routes are: "
cat ${ROUTES_FILE}
```